# Hibernate Criteria condition A - B > C

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

How to define hibernate criterion to generate SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnA - columnB > anyInteger
```

?
I know there is:

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("column_a - column_b > "+int);
```

but it dependts on columns names, not the class properties. Any way how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found solution, not the workaround. I had to create new implementation of Criterion class. Here's the code :

```
public class DifferenceCriterion implements Criterion{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8082375591482621375L;

    private String firstProperty;
    private String secondProperty;
    private int value;

    public DifferenceCriterion(String propertyA, String propertyB, int value) {
        this.firstProperty = propertyA;
        this.secondProperty = propertyB;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedValue[] getTypedValues(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
        TypedValue tvFirst = criteriaQuery.getTypedValue(criteria, firstProperty, value);
        TypedValue tvSecond = criteriaQuery.getTypedValue(criteria, secondProperty, value);
        if(!tvFirst.equals(tvSecond)){
            throw new HibernateException("Properties typedValues are not the same!");
        }
        return new TypedValue[] {tvFirst};
    }

    @Override
    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
        final String[] columnsA = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, this.firstProperty);
        final String[] columnsB = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, this.secondProperty);
        return columnsA[0] + " - "+columnsB[0] + " >  ?";
    }
}
```

and type in my criteria query method:

```
criteria.add(new DifferenceCriterion("columnA", "columnB", someInt));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid having to express the restriction in terms of column names if you want to be able to query on it, because the calculation has to happen in the database side rather than the Java side.  But what you could do is map an additional property as a [*formula*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785) to encapsulate the SQL in the Hibernate mapping definition rather than having to repeat it every time you query:

```
@Formula("column_a - column_b")
private int difference;
```

You would then query it as

```
Restrictions.gt("difference", value)
```